# jq sort by version as string

Tags: json, sorting, version, jq

I'm trying to sort the following json reponse to pick the latest version:

```
[
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.11"
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.1.8"
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.10",
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.9",
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.77"
    }
]
```

Correct sorting should be:

```
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.9",
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.10",
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.11"
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.0.77"
    },
    {
        "TagVersion": "1.1.8"
    }
```

I'm currently able to do part of the job. It's working for simple cases (all version part major/minor/bug has the same number of digits).

`jq -r [.[]]|max_by(.TagVersion|split(".") | map(tonumber)`

The best way to do it in my mind should be to add a multiplication the each part. Example:

```
# With condition than every "part" as a maximum of 2 digits. It won't work with 3 digits

# Version 1.23.87

1 * 1000 + 23 * 10 + 87 = 1317

# Version 3.0.0
1 * 1000 + 0 * 10 + 0 = 3000

# Version 1.89.78
1 * 1000 + 89*10 + 78 = 1968
```

Does anybody have an idea to implement this?

Comment: 100% correct. My bad. But you go the idea. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turn each component into a number, then sort on the array of integers.

```
jq 'sort_by(.TagVersion|split(".")|map(tonumber))'
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "TagVersion": "1.0.9"
  },
  {
    "TagVersion": "1.0.10"
  },
  {
    "TagVersion": "1.0.11"
  },
  {
    "TagVersion": "1.0.77"
  },
  {
    "TagVersion": "1.1.8"
  }
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. But I thought is was not working 100% of the time. What is the magic here? `tonumber` shouldn't it convert `1.0.77` to `1077` and `1.1.8` to `118` ? 

Comment: @brcebn: `split(".")` results in `["1", "0", "77"]`; then `map(tonumber)` applies `tonumber` to each element, producing `[1, 0, 77]`. `jq` knows how to sort an array of integers correctly, and also how to sort by one (as shown in my output).

Comment: Shouldn't "1.1.8" sort before "1.1.10" instead of after "1.0.77"?  I don't understand why "1.0.9" sorts correctly before "1.0.10".

Comment: @StephenRasku There is no "1.1.10". And "1.0.10" is before "1.1.8" in minor version, so patch version does not matter.

Comment: Ah, so it is, @Amadan.  Apologies for the mis-reading.

Answer (score 2):

This one allows you to use full [Semantic Versioning 2.0 ordering](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html#spec-item-11) including `-pre.release` suffixes.

```bash
jq_semver_cmp='                                           
  def opt(f):
      . as $in | try f catch $in;
  def semver_cmp:
      sub("\\+.*$"; "")
    | capture("^(?<v>[^-]+)(?:-(?<p>.*))?$") | [.v, .p // empty]
    | map(split(".") | map(opt(tonumber)))
    | .[1] |= (. // {});'

jq "$jq_semver_cmp"'sort_by(.TagVersion|semver_cmp)'
```

As it uses a couple tricks, I might explain it. In general, the `semver_cmp` function chomps the version string into a 2-level array that `jq`-natively sorts as desired. The array looks like this:

```json
 "0.1.0":         [[0,1,0],{}]
 "0.1.0-alpha.2": [[0,1,0],["alpha", 2]]
```

1. `sub("\\+.*$"; "")` strips any eventual [metadata](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html#spec-item-10), that doesn't take part in the comparison.
2. `capture("^(?<v>[^-]+)(?:-(?<p>.*))?$") | [.v, .p // empty]` splits the string into an array like `["x.y.z"]` or `["x.y.z", "pre.release"]` if the [pre-release suffix](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html#spec-item-9) exists.
3. `map(split(".") | map(opt(tonumber)))` splits these elements further by `.` and where possible, it converts the "identifiers" to numbers (to sort numerically).
4. `.[1] |= (. // {})` is a little trick that adds an empty object as the 2nd element for plain version strings that don't have the suffix. [Objects  sort after arrays](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sort,sort_by(path_expression)), which is what we need here.

With that sorted out, an input like this:

```json
[
    { "TagVersion": "1.0.11" },
    { "TagVersion": "1.0.11-alpha.2" },
    { "TagVersion": "1.0.11-alpha" }
]
```

will correctly end up like this - with the plain version sorted after the pre-release.

```json
[
    { "TagVersion": "1.0.11-alpha" },
    { "TagVersion": "1.0.11-alpha.2" },
    { "TagVersion": "1.0.11" }
]
```